# Angular 2+: Accessing Reactive Forms independently with Validation in ngFor loop

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, ngfor, angular-reactive-forms

I am working with a Reactive form. I have 2 sets of data. They are:

1. **List of Items** - Contains Item ID and Item Name
2. **List of Groups** - Contains Group ID and Group Name

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

1. In the UI, I am looping through the Items and showing the Item ID and Item Name. Works fine.
2. I am looping through the Groups and showing the Group ID and Group Name in a Select box. Works fine too.
3. I place the Select box from point 2 above, in the ngFor loop of the Items in point 1 above, so that **each Item can be assigned to a Group**. Let's say that I click on the first Select box with the intention of assigning a Group from the list, for the First Item. Then instead of clicking on any of the options shown, I click away somewhere else on the page. **This action shows error message for all the other form controls/select boxes on the page as well.** If I select a value for any of the other select boxes in rest of the page, then the error message for even the first dropdown is cleared.  **This is the issue and this should not happen. The error should show up only for the Select box that is paired with the First Item and not for the other select boxes in the page that are meant to be paired with other Items. Each of those errors should show up independently for each of those forms.**

**SUMMARY OF THE ISSUE:**

**I am trying to assign a Group to each of those Items**. So I am trying to fix the (above) connected behavior of the forms, so that **each form should work independently of the other in the loop** and after selecting a Group, when the **"Assign Group"** button is clicked, I am trying to access the corresponding Item ID and Group ID of only the form that was submitted and not the other forms. How can this be achieved with proper Validation/Errors showing up for the submitted forms, as and when they are accessed?

**LIVE DEMO OF THE ISSUE:**

I have already setup a [StackBlitz demo here](https://loop-reactive-forms.stackblitz.io/) replicating the issue.

**LIVE DEMO EDITOR CODE:**

Here is the [Live Demo Editor code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/loop-reactive-forms)

Comment: you're looping over `allData` but reusing the same `formGroup` instance which seems weird

Comment: Yes, that's why I am posting my question as I do not know what to change here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually with your code angular understand that there's one Form (formControlName) called: partnerGroupsId so all of them are linked with same ID and name

LIVE SOLUTION : https://angular-2-accessing-reactive-forms-independently.stackblitz.io

LIVE EDIT CODE : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2-accessing-reactive-forms-independently

SOLUTION :

You need to loop through your data (this.allData) to build form Builder groups :

```
const groups = {};

for(let i = 0; i< this.allData.length; i++) {
  groups['partnerGroupsId' + i] = ['', [
            Validators.required,
  ]];
}

this.applicationForm = this.formBuilder.group(
        groups
);
```

and use the below HTML :

```
<ul class="pb-0">
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of allData; let i = index">
    <li>
        <label class="label">
            {{item.item_name}} /
             <span class="label-heading">Item ID # {{item.item_id}}</span>
        </label>
    <form [formGroup]="applicationForm" (ngSubmit)="assignGroup()"
          (keyup.enter)="assignGroup()"
          class="full-width">
          <label position="floating">Select Group</label>
          <select formControlName="partnerGroupsId{{ i }}">
            <option value="">Select a Group from this list</option>
              <option *ngFor="let partnerGroups of allDataGroups;"
                      value="{{partnerGroups.group_id}}" selected>
                  {{partnerGroups.display_name}}
              </option>                  
          </select>
      <div class="validaterrors">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validationMessages.partnerGroupsId;"   >
              <div class="error-message"
                    *ngIf="applicationForm.get('partnerGroupsId' + i).hasError(validation.type) && (applicationForm.get('partnerGroupsId' + i).dirty || applicationForm.get('partnerGroupsId' + i).touched)">
                  {{ validation.message }}
              </div>
          </ng-container>
      </div>

        <button color="primary" expand="block" type="submit" class="">
            Assign Group
        </button>
    </form>
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I noticed that in your code, the value of `myid` is shown as Not a Number i.e. as  `myid NaN`. Can you please rectify this and share the link to the Editor for your code so that I can understand it better? Also it looks like that you Fork'ed my repo, so the changes you made, are **NOT** visible in my repo.

Comment: Here you go i just updated the answer this is the [editor link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2-accessing-reactive-forms-independently)

Comment: In this case, how can I pass the value of the selected option for `partnerGroupsId{{ i }}` to the function `assignGroup()` ?

Comment: can you replace that select element with this



`<select formControlName="partnerGroupsId{{ i }}" (change)="assignGroup(item.item_id, groupvalue.value)" #groupvalue>
                <option value="">Select a Group from this list</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let partnerGroups of allDataGroups;"
                          value="{{partnerGroups.group_id}}" selected>
                      {{partnerGroups.display_name}}
                  </option>                  
              </select>`

Comment: You can get the assigned group value with the formControlName="partnerGroupsId{{ i }}"

Comment: I have completed the function assignGroup() as you wanted following the actual structure [Check live edit code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2-accessing-reactive-forms-independently)

Comment: **THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!** Appreciate it! I am trying to allot the Bounty to you, but it seems like SO is making me wait for it. I will be doing it as soon as SO lets me do that.

Answer (score 0):

The loop you're using inside the template is creating multiple forms all using the same FormControl.
There's a couple of ways to fix this, one using a FormArray, but I think using the `item_id` attribute for the FormControl id is the simplest that way you can access the control in the template using `form.controls[id]`

```
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  allData = [
            {
                "item_name": "Test 1",
                "item_id": "1",
            },
            {
                "item_name": "Test 2",
                "item_id": "2",
            },
            {
                "item_name": "Test 3",
                "item_id": "3",
            },
            {
                "item_name": "Test 4",
                "item_id": "4",
            },
            {
                "item_name": "Test 5",
                "item_id": "5",
            },
        ];
  allDataGroups = [
            {
                "display_name": "Group 1",
                "group_id": "1",
            },
            {
                "display_name": "Group 2",
                "group_id": "2",
            },
            {
                "display_name": "Group 3",
                "group_id": "3",
            }
        ];

  constructor() {
    this.createFormControls()
  }

  private createFormControls() {
    for (const datum of this.allData) {
      const id = datum.item_id;
      this.form.addControl(id, new FormControl())
    }
  }
```

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div *ngFor="let datum of allData">
      <span>{{ datum.item_name }} / Item ID #{{ datum.item_id }}</span>
      <select style="display: block" [formControlName]="datum.item_id">
        <option *ngFor="let group of allDataGroups" [value]="group.group_id">
          {{ group.display_name }}
        </option>
      </select>
      <button>Assign Group</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a demo using your code but it does not seem to work. I mean, the validation part is not being triggered at all. Please check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/loop-reactive-forms-try-1

Comment: The above code is for accessing the form controls individually and it does work. If you need to access errors you can do so by accessing the form control itself with ```form.controls[id].errors``` for the object of errors or ```form.controls[id].getError(errorKey)``` for the individual error

Comment: I need to access the Validation/Errors individually as that is the core of the requirement (maybe you missed it in the title). Can you please fork your code (the link that I shared almost 50 min ago) and make the necessary changes to your code and share its `Editor link` with me so that I can understand your code better?

Answer (score 0):

Do a for loop and then put each form in it's own component.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of group">
   <custom-form [item]="item"></custom-form>
</div>
```

Everything that happens in custom-form, stays in custom-form, which is what you want. You could use an `eventEmitter` of course if you want to send the result up the chain.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at multiple stack overflow headers. In Array, I developed a dynamic structure according to how many staff there are. A more practical and sharp answer without using **FormArray**.

FormArray examples are confusing and if there is an array of data available, it is unnecessary for me.

I realized that I used a similar structure more practically in my project. I hope I can help everyone a little bit.

**form.component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="coordinateFormGroup">
    <div class="coordinate-item" *ngFor="let coordinate of coordinates; index as i" fxLayout="row"
        fxLayoutAlign="start center">
        <div class="circle">
            {{ coordinate.label }}
        </div>
        <div class="source-type">
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select formControlName="sourceType{{ i + 1 }}"
                    placeholder="Select Soruce Type..."
                    required>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let source of sources$ | async" [value]="source">
                        {{ source.title }}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
                <mat-error *ngIf="coordinateControls({ 
                    controlName: 'sourceType', 
                    index: i, 
                    errorName: 'required' })">
                    Required
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <div class="add-photo">
            <button mat-icon-button aria-label="take a photo">
                <mat-icon>camera_alt</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="!this.coordinateFormGroup.valid">
        SUBMIT
    </button>
</form>
```

**form.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SourcesQuery, SourcesGQL } from '@generated-types';

interface Coordinate {
  lat: number,
  lng: number
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})

export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  coordinateFormGroup: FormGroup;
  coordinates: Coordinate[] = [];
  sources$: Observable<SourcesQuery['sources']>; // for option select

  constructor(
    private sourcesGQL: SourcesGQL,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSources(); // async

    // init coordinate form group
    this.coordinateFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      // must be added for each coordinate object.
    });

  }

  // cleaner error caller on the html side, also a shortcut to walk through the index
  coordinateControls({ controlName, index, errorName }: { controlName: string, index: number, errorName: string }): boolean {
    // bring errors for each different formControlName in the loop.
    const name = `${controlName}${index + 1}`;
    return this.coordinateFormGroup.controls[name].hasError(errorName);
  }

  // Data from the coordinate service.
  // The data emitted are reprocessed here in real time with formBuilder.
  // This function works whenever data changes.
  getCoordinateCache(coordinates: Coordinate[]): Coordinate[] {
    this.coordinates = coordinates;

    // we rebuild the form group every time.
    this.coordinateFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({

    });

    // we add new formControl for each coordinate.
    coordinates.forEach((obj, i) => {
      this.coordinateFormGroup.addControl(`sourceType${i + 1}`, new FormControl('', [Validators.required]));
    });

    console.log(this.coordinateFormGroup);
    return this.coordinates;
  }

  // Data received for option select.
  getSources(): void {
    this.sources$ = this.sourcesGQL
      .watch({ keyword: '', skip: 0, take: 0 })
      .valueChanges.pipe(map(({ data }) => {
        return data.sources;
      }));
  }


}
```

**screenshoot**
[image]